# How to set a default layout in Magento 1.5 using local.xml?

Tags: xml, layout, magento, default

So I've done some layouts that I want to use and I was thinking that setting this in your local.xml file would fix this for every page. Like this

```
<default>
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
      <template>page/mytheme.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
</default>
```

This however doesn't do anything. Instead if I go

```
...<customer_account_forgotpassword>
  <reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/mytheme.phtml</template></action>
  </reference>
</customer_account_forgotpassword>  

<customer_account_confirmation>
  <reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/mytheme.phtml</template></action>
  </reference>
</customer_account_confirmation>...
```

and so on for every specific place it gets changed on those specific pages. Am I thinking wrong or this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem you're (probably) running into is that something comes along later and sets the template for the root block **again**, overriding your change.

More recent versions of Magento (1.4somethingish) introduced a way to prevent this from happening.  If you look in `page.xml`, you'll see a handle like this

```
<page_one_column translate="label">
    <label>All One-Column Layout Pages</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
</page_one_column>
```

If the `page_one_column` handle gets applied to your request, or you manually apply it with

```
<update handle="page_one_column" />
```

Magento will change the template **and** call the `setIsHandle` method on the block.

```
<action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
```

There's code in Magento that will look for the IsHandle property, and if it's true, further calls to `setTemplate` will be ignored. (that's over-simplifying things a bit, but is more or less true)

Try something like

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
          <template>page/mytheme.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setIsHandle">
            <applied>1</applied>
        </action>       
    </reference>
</default>
```

And see if that helps.

Keep in mind this is one of those grey areas where it's not clear if third party developers are supposed to tread.  Also, changing the template for all pages **may** have un-desirable effect on parts of the site that expect to be in a certain template.

Comment: it is pity, but setIsHandle method is used for different purpose. The idea behind it just to keep page layouts backward compatible, because previous versions had possibility to set only template, but later on, it was changed to handle, that is more flexible. If is_handle property is set to true, it just will not set template in page/layout helper, but it will apply the page handle, that sets the template, so template will be set anyway, just the way how it is set, will be different.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you are the on the right track. You just didn't specify the request on your `local.xml`. You should also include the request you are overriding.

Here is a example code of `local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <default>
    ....
    </default>

    <!-- Update Configuration for this request specially -->
    <customer_account_confirmation> 
      <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/mytheme.phtml</template></action>
      </reference>
    </customer_account_confirmation>

</layout>
```

*This much configuration is **enough** to do, what you need.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems that you have to add it to some of the individual handles themselves. That's because the `<default>` handle is the first one that is loaded. The `<customer_account_forgotpassword>` handle is only read later. If you check the file `design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml` you will see that this very same handle sets a different template than the `<default>` one.

Look at this example of the order that the layout handles are read by Magento for the "Forgot Password" page:

```
1. default
2. STORE_default
3. THEME_frontend_default_babel
4. customer_account_forgotpassword
5. customer_logged_out
```

There you can see why the `<default>` handle's template setting is overridden.

I recommend you use the Layout Viewer module for Magento by Alan Storm: http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and thought it might save someones time.
 Was trying to set `1column` layout to **cms pages**. None of the solutions worked until I realized:
 **CMS page template is set from Admin** `CMS > Pages > Design > Layout`, not local.xml.
 If you set template for `<default>` handle in `local.xml`, it does not help, because this will be overrided by layout handle choosen from Admin pages for each specific CMS page.