# How to 'force' Magento to load only one template

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a generic template file that I would like to be used for every page. I have witnessed a co-worker add a single parameter to either his local.xml or page.xml layout file that forced every page to use the specific layout file regardless of database values. He has since left the company so I cannot ask him how he did it. I have tried the answer as suggested in [How to set a default layout in Magento 1.5 using local.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550764/how-to-set-a-default-layout-in-magento-1-5-using-local-xml) but that did not work.

How do I force Magento (1.7) to load only the template/layout that I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pity, but there is not just single option that you can use to be sure that all page layouts will use your templates, but you can apply your layout handle that will set your custom template in each of the page layout handles.

So in your local.xml there should be something like the following:

```
<your_custom_handle>
     <action method="setTemplate" block="root"><template>your/template.phtml</template></action>
</your_custom_handle>

<page_empty>
     <update handle="your_custom_handle" />
</page_empty>

<page_one_column>
     <update handle="your_custom_handle" />
</page_one_column>

<page_two_columns_left>
     <update handle="your_custom_handle" />
</page_two_columns_left>

<page_two_columns_right>
     <update handle="your_custom_handle" />
</page_two_columns_right>

<page_three_columns>
     <update handle="your_custom_handle" />
</page_three_columns>
```

The first part of the layout update, creates your own handle, that sets template to root block. All the others are including your custom handle into different page layouts.

Enjoy!

Comment: While this does work, I need to include the handle of every type of page being called ever on the site. Is there a definitive list somewhere of these?

Comment: I already provided you a list of all the custom page layout handles that exists in standard Magento installment.

Comment: All the other pages usually use them. For also you can add this change to `<default>` handle as well.

Comment: To this list I also need to add `
  <catalog_product_view>
    <update handle="your_custom_handle" />
  </catalog_product_view>` for my products page to use my template. Is what makes me suspect I needed to do this for more handles than was suggested. Maybe this is another thing that Magento broke in 1.7?

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King it is because in catalog.xml in core it sets template not by handle, but by manually specifying template. See lines 181-183 of base/default theme layout/catalog.xml file.

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King You also could use an event observer to grab the root block and add the handle. Have a look at this recent question, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577155/magento-add-content-block-at-the-end-of-the-structual-block-content/11599046#11599046

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Ivans answer, you also can use event observers to set the template. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577155/magento-add-content-block-at-the-end-of-the-structual-block-content/11599046#11599046) for a longer explanation. This is the code you can use:

app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/layout/local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <!-- your other adjustments for default, category_product_view and so on go here -->

    <set_root_template>
        <reference name="root">
             <action method="setTemplate"><template>your/template.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </set_root_template>
</layout>
```

app/code/yourpool/Company/Extension/Model/Observer.php

```
    <?php

    class Company_Extension_Model_Observer
    {
        /**
         * Sets the template file for the root block.
         * 
         * Uses the event 'controller_action_layout_load_before'.
         * 
         * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
         * @return YourCompany_YourExtension_Model_Observer
         */
        public function setRootTemplate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
            $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
            $layout->addHandle('set_root_template');
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

app/code/yourpool/Company/Extension/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Extension>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Company_Extension>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <company_extension_set_root_template>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>company_extension/observer</class>
                        <method>setRootTemplate</method>
                    </company_extension_set_root_template>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
        </events>
        <!-- declaring your layout xml etc. -->
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <!-- declaring your block classes etc. -->
        <models>
            <company_extension>
                <class>Company_Extension_Model</class>
            </company_extension>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/etc/modules/Company_Extension.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Extension>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Company_Extension>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

And as another alternative. (but essentially the same as what @MatthiasZeis) suggests. I am just also supplying a module to do it with)

I had the same issue, and I came up with the same idea of injecting a custom handle into magento, using observer events.

thus my code injects a 'load last' handle called `<GLOBAL_OVERRIDE>`, which then allows you to set the root template via layout directive.

Since it loads last, any previous set layout directive to change the template is replaced with the one in `<GLOBAL_OVERRIDE>`

```
<GLOBAL_OVERRIDE>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </GLOBAL_OVERRIDE>
```

You can just as easily use this to globally remove another handle, or unset a child block through the entire site

I placed the code in github:

https://github.com/ProxiBlue/GlobalHandle